# Convergence of a hypergeometric function

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, mathematica, hypergeometric-function

The hypergeometric function, ${}_{2}F_1(a,b,c;z)$ can be written in terms of a power series in $z$ as follows, $${}_{2}F_1(a,b,c;z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_n (b)_n}{(c)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}\,\,\,\,\,\text{provided}\,\,\,\,|z|<1$$

So we may reexpress any hypergeometric function as a power series like this as long as the last argument modulus is less than $1$

My question is, I also have an expansion of a hypergeometric of the form ${}_2 F_1(a,b+\epsilon, c- \epsilon, z)$ by using the HypExp package on Mathematica (expansion in $\epsilon$) and was wondering if I use this expansion do I also require $|z|<1$? When I write the code in Mathematica, the last argument is replaced by simply $x$ say and Mathematica gives me an expansion regardless of the size of $x$ so I am thinking ${\it this}$ expansion is maybe valid independent of $|x|$ but would be nice to confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: Evaluate the asymptotics of $\dfrac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n~n!~~}$ using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), to deduce the convergence radius of *z*.

Comment: @Lucian: Would that not give me the $|z|<1$ convergence?